# Flex - how to Embed multiple fonts in spark RichText with CSS?

Tags: css, apache-flex, fonts, embed

I'm trying to embed multiple fonts in a spark RichText component but not sure how to go about it. I'm wanting to be able to display bold font using  tags in HTML. With the font i'm using, the regular and bold character sets are in different .ttf files.

Can I set more than one font family in CSS for a component?

Here is my stylesheet so far...

```
@font-face { 
    src: url("/styles/fonts/FontRg.ttf"); 
    fontFamily: FontRg_CFF; 
    fontStyle: normal; 
    fontWeight: normal; 
    embedAsCFF: true;
}

@font-face { 
    src: url("/styles/fonts/FontRgBd.ttf"); 
    fontFamily: FontRgBd_CFF; 
    fontStyle: normal; 
    fontWeight: normal; 
    embedAsCFF: true; 
}

s|RichText{ 
    font-family: FontRg_CFF;
    font-size: 16;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Though this post is pretty old, I just had the same issue and could figure out how it works:
You will have to change the following in order to display the bold text:

```
@font-face { 
    src: url("/styles/fonts/FontRgBd.ttf"); 
    fontFamily: FontRg_CFF; 
    fontStyle: normal; 
    fontWeight: bold; 
    embedAsCFF: true; 
}
```

So, **fontFamily** and **fontWeight** need to be changed like you see above. Both embeds need to share the same fontFamily name whereas the bold font needs to have the fontWeight being set to "bold".

You can then simply use b-tags (`<b>BOLD</b>`) to display bold text within Flex RichText or TextArea.

Answer (score -1):

I notice that in both of your font declarations you have only embedded the normal weight. Try another font declaration for the bold version.